# Merging 3 immutable maps in scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have 3 immutable maps

```scala
as: Map[UUID, A]
bs: Map[UUID, B]
cs: Map[UUID, C]
```

and I want to merge them so the result is of type:

```scala
Map[UUID, (Option[A], Option[B], Option[C])]
```

What is the best way to do this. And by best I mean fewest lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to iterate all keys and construct the value for each of them. Something like this:

```
val keys = as.keySet ++ bs.keySet ++ cs.keySet
val merged = keys.map(key => (key, (as.get(key), bs.get(key), cs.get(key)))).toMap
```

Comment: small typo `cs.get(key)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use for comprehension:

```
for {
  k <- as.keySet ++ bs.keySet ++ cs.keySet
} yield (as.get(k), bs.get(k), cs.get(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want a better data type that knows that at least one of the elements has to be defined. And since you mentioned **cats** you may do this:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

val result = ((as align bs) align cs)
```

That gives you a `Map[UUID, Ior[Ior[A, B], C]]` which properly represents that the result can either be a single element, a pair, or the three.